# App is missing in SharePoint site site contents -- > add an app --> From your organization

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I added app in app catalog. But this app is missing in "from your organization". Not able to see that app.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Is this a custom app, or one from the store?  Is this a local deployment or Office 365?

Comment: What are the permissions given to app?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the language dependent fix 2017 CU?

I once had the same issue but finally resolved it following this link:

> In short, install the language dependent update that comes with the
>   CU, then delete the App Catalog, create the catalog again, upload the
>   app, give rights on the app catalog to the user. And then finally you
>   will see your app in "Add an app" section

See https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/331